# Scalar angle between two quaternions

Tags: c++, c, math

Is it possible to calculate the difference between two quaternions and represent it as a scalar?

I want to provide an API which can be used to set a minimum threshold angle in degrees (or Radians). And use that value to notify when a 3D object is rotated more than the threshold in any axis.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1755631/951890

Comment: You should also take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/quaternion-distance